# Show input text-box on the row of the table when an option is selected on a drop-down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with three columns for **machine type**, **serial number** and **delete**. I have a button above the table which adds a row on the table and I have a button within that added row which remove the row once it's clicked. That part works fine. Within the added row I have a dropdown list which is machine type and the second input for serial numbers. Two options on the drop-down list go hand in hand. I can select an option on the drop down list and get input to enter a serial number, which works fine. The problem starts when I add the second row and choose a different option it changes the input of the first row to the one of the second input.

On my drop-down list, I have an option of **others** when **others** is selected I have to give the user an option to enter machine type on input textbox and serial number on a textbox. Which also works fine. Only when I add the second row it does not work.

I hope I have explained what I m trying to accomplish.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<!-- Other Machine Accessories -->
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">                                  
                                <div class="resize">
                                <h5>Other Machine Accessories</h5>                                  
                                    <p><input type="button" class="btn btn-success"  value="Add More"></p>
                                    <table id="otherMachineAccessories" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Machine Type</th>
                                                    <th>Serial Number</th>
                                                    <th>Delete</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <select id="machineAccessories" name="machineAccessories" class="form-control" onchange="CheckMachineAccessories(this.value);">
                                                            <option value="">Please select Machine Accessories</option>
                                                            <option value="Bridge Unit">Bridge Unit</option>
                                                            <option value="Finisher">Finisher</option>
                                                            <option value="Fax Unit">Fax Unit</option>
                                                            <option value="One Bin Tray">One Bin Tray</option>                                                  
                                                            <option value="LCT">LCT</option>
                                                            <option value="Credenza">Credenza</option>
                                                            <option value="Additional Paper Trays">Additional Paper Trays</option>
                                                            <option value="Wireless Card">Wireless Card</option>
                                                            <option value="Others">Others</option>
                                                        </select>                                                               
                                                        <input name="others" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" style="display:none;" id="othersMachineType" placeholder="Please Enetr Machine Type" class="form-control" type="text"/>       
                                                    </td>                                                           
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div class="bridgeAndFinisher" id="bridgeFinisher" style="display:none;">
                                                            <input name="bridgeUnitSerialTypeSerialNo" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" id="bridgeFinisher" placeholder="Please Enter Bridge Unit Serial" class="form-control" type="text"><br>
                                                            <input name="finisherTypeSerialNo" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" placeholder="Please Enter Finisher Serial" id="bridgeFinisher" class="form-control" type="text">
                                                        </div>
                                                        <input name="faxUnitSerialTypeSerialNo" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" style="display:none;" id="faxUnitSerial" placeholder="Please Enter Fax Unit Serial" class="form-control" type="text"/>
                                                        <input name="OneBinTrayTypeSerialNo" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" style="display:none;" id="oneBinTraySerial" placeholder="Please Enter One Bin Tray Serial" class="form-control" type="text"/>
                                                        <input name="ltcTypeSerial" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" style="display:none;" id="lctSerial" placeholder="Please Enter LCT Serial" class="form-control" type="text"/>
                                                        <input name="creTypeserial" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" style="display:none;" id="credenzaSerial" placeholder="Please Enter Credenza Serial" class="form-control" type="text"/>
                                                        <input name="addTypeserial" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" style="display:none;" id="additionalPaperTraysSerial" placeholder="Please Enter Additional Paper Trays Serial"  class="form-control" type="text"/>
                                                        <input name="wirelessCard" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" style="display:none;" id="wirelessCardSerial" placeholder="Please Enetr Wireless Card Serial" class="form-control" type="text"/>
                                                        <input name="others" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" style="display:none;" id="othersSerial" placeholder="Please Enetr Serial" class="form-control" type="text"/>      

                                                    </td>
                                                    <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove" /></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                    </table>                    
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- //Other Machine Accessories -->
```

My script

```
<!---Script to add other Accossory-->
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#otherMachineAccessories').on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    })
$('p input[type="button"]').click(function () {
    $('#otherMachineAccessories').append('<tr><td><select id="machineAccessories" name="machineAccessories" class="form-control" onchange="CheckMachineAccessories(this.value);"><option value="">Please select Machine Accessories</option><option value="Bridge Unit">Bridge Unit</option><option value="Finisher">Finisher</option><option value="Fax Unit">Fax Unit</option><option value="One Bin Tray">One Bin Tray</option><option value="LCT">LCT</option><option value="Credenza">Credenza</option><option value="Additional Paper Trays">Additional Paper Trays</option><option value="Wireless Card">Wireless Card</option><option value="others">Others</option></select><input name="others" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" style="display:none;" id="othersMachineType" placeholder="Please Enetr Machine Type" class="form-control" type="text"/></div></td><td><div class="bridgeAndFinisher" id="bridgeFinishere" style="display:none;"><input name="bridgeUnitSerialTypeSerialNo" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" id="bridgeFinishere" placeholder="Please Enter Bridge Unit Serial" class="form-control" type="text"/><br><input name="finisherTypeSerialNo" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" id="bridgeFinishere" placeholder="Please Enter Finisher Serial" class="form-control" type="text"/></div><input name="faxUnitSerialTypeSerialNo" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" style="display:none;" id="faxUnitSerial" placeholder="Please Enter Fax Unit Serial" class="form-control" type="text"/><input name="OneBinTrayTypeSerialNo" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" style="display:none;" placeholder="Please Enter One Bin Tray Serial" id="oneBinTraySerial" class="form-control" type="text"/><input name="ltcTypeSerial" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)"style="display:none;" placeholder="Please Enter LCT Serial" id="lctSerial" class="form-control" type="text"/><input name="creTypeserial" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" style="display:none;" id="credenzaSerial" placeholder="Please Enter Credenza Serial" class="form-control" type="text"/><input name="addTypeserial" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" style="display:none;" id="additionalPaperTraysSerial" placeholder="Please Enter Additional Paper Trays Serial"  class="form-control" type="text"/><input name="wirelessCard" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" style="display:none;" id="wirelessCardSerial" placeholder="Please Wireless Card Serial" class="form-control" type="text"/><input name="others" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" style="display:none;" id="othersSerial" placeholder="Please Enetr Serial" class="form-control" type="text"/></td><td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove" /></td></tr>')
});

</script>

<!--Machine Accessories Selection-->
<script type="text/javascript">

    function CheckMachineAccessories(val){

        var element=document.getElementById('bridgeFinisher');
        if(val=='pick machine type' || val=='Bridge Unit' || val=='Finisher')
           element.style.display='block';
         else  
           element.style.display='none';

       var element=document.getElementById('bridgeFinisher');
       if(val=='pick machine type' || val=='Bridge Unit' || val=='Finisher')
           element.style.display='block';
         else  
           element.style.display='none';

        var element=document.getElementById('faxUnitSerial');
        if(val=='pick machine type' || val=='Fax Unit')
           element.style.display='block';
         else  
           element.style.display='none';

        var element=document.getElementById('oneBinTraySerial');
        if(val=='pick machine type' || val=='One Bin Tray')
           element.style.display='block';
         else  
           element.style.display='none';

        var element=document.getElementById('lctSerial');
        if(val=='pick machine type' || val=='LCT')
           element.style.display='block';
         else  
           element.style.display='none';

        var element=document.getElementById('credenzaSerial');
        if(val=='pick machine type' || val=='Credenza')
           element.style.display='block';
         else  
           element.style.display='none';

        var element=document.getElementById('additionalPaperTraysSerial');
        if (val=='pick machine type' || val=='Additional Paper Trays')
             element.style.display='block';
         else  
           element.style.display='none';

        var element=document.getElementById('wirelessCardSerial');
        if (val=='pick machine type' || val=='Wireless Card')
             element.style.display='block';
         else  
           element.style.display='none';

        var element=document.getElementById('othersSerial');
        if (val=='pick machine type' || val=='Others')
             element.style.display='block';
         else  
           element.style.display='none';

        var element=document.getElementById('othersMachineType');
        if (val=='pick machine type' || val=='Others')
             element.style.display='block';
         else  
           element.style.display='none';
           console.log(val);
    }

</script>
```

Here is my code on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/JayStar/pen/gRgKvx?editors=1010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are having is that in HTML documents, IDs should only be assigned to one element only. Since all your inputs share the same IDs for each row, any call to document.getElementById will just return the first element it finds in the first row.

There are numerous ways to solve this, but one way you can try is assign a unique ID to each row in your table and use the name attribute on each of your inputs. Then when you are trying to call CheckMachineAccessories, pass in that unique ID as well. Then instead of using document.getElementById, you can do something like

```
var element = $("#uniqueRowId [name='bridgeFinisher']")[0]
```

**EDIT**

Here is some clarification:

You want to ensure that each element with an ID has a unique ID. So there are couple things you need to do. First is to make sure that the rows you add have a unique ID on the row.

```
//We are starting with 2, because there is already a row in the grid.
var rowId = 2;
$('p input[type="button"]').click(function () {
    $('#otherMachineAccessories').append('<tr id="machineAccessoryRow-' + rowId + '"><td><select id="machineAccessories" name="machineAccessories" class="form-control" onchange="CheckMachineAccessories(this.value, ' + rowId + ');"><option value="">Please select Machine Accessories</option><option value="Bridge Unit">Bridge Unit</option><option value="Finisher">Finisher</option><option value="Fax Unit">Fax Unit</option><option value="One Bin Tray">One Bin Tray</option><option value="LCT">LCT</option><option value="Credenza">Credenza</option><option value="Additional Paper Trays">Additional Paper Trays</option><option value="Wireless Card">Wireless Card</option><option value="others">Others</option></select><input name="others" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" style="display:none;" id="othersMachineType" placeholder="Please Enetr Machine Type" class="form-control" type="text"/></div></td><td><div class="bridgeAndFinisher" id="bridgeFinishere" style="display:none;"><input name="bridgeUnitSerialTypeSerialNo" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" id="bridgeFinishere" placeholder="Please Enter Bridge Unit Serial" class="form-control" type="text"/><br><input name="finisherTypeSerialNo" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" id="bridgeFinishere" placeholder="Please Enter Finisher Serial" class="form-control" type="text"/></div><input name="faxUnitSerialTypeSerialNo" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" style="display:none;" id="faxUnitSerial" placeholder="Please Enter Fax Unit Serial" class="form-control" type="text"/><input name="OneBinTrayTypeSerialNo" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" style="display:none;" placeholder="Please Enter One Bin Tray Serial" id="oneBinTraySerial" class="form-control" type="text"/><input name="ltcTypeSerial" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)"style="display:none;" placeholder="Please Enter LCT Serial" id="lctSerial" class="form-control" type="text"/><input name="creTypeserial" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" style="display:none;" id="credenzaSerial" placeholder="Please Enter Credenza Serial" class="form-control" type="text"/><input name="addTypeserial" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" style="display:none;" id="additionalPaperTraysSerial" placeholder="Please Enter Additional Paper Trays Serial"  class="form-control" type="text"/><input name="wirelessCard" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" style="display:none;" id="wirelessCardSerial" placeholder="Please Wireless Card Serial" class="form-control" type="text"/><input name="others" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" style="display:none;" id="othersSerial" placeholder="Please Enetr Serial" class="form-control" type="text"/></td><td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove" /></td></tr>')

  rowId++;
});
```

An example like this will create the new rows with unique Ids. After that, you want to pass down the Id to CheckMachineAccessories and filter your elements based on it.

```
function CheckMachineAccessories(val, rowId){
  var element = $("#machineAccessoryRow-" + rowId + " [name='bridgeFinisher']")[0];
  if(val=='pick machine type' || val=='Bridge Unit' || val=='Finisher') {
    element.style.display='block';
  }
  else { 
    element.style.display='none';
  }
}
```

Comment: I hope I get you. Will this uniqueRowId have to be done in my HTML and javascript
for **HTML**
`<td id="uniqueRowId">`
and **JS** `$('#otherMachineAccessories').append('<tr><td id="uniqueRowId">`

Comment: Edited the answer for more clarification.

Comment: I get the following on the console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at CheckMachineAccessories (machine.html:85)
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange `

Comment: I have changed `element.style.display='block';` to `$(this).show();` now I dont get any error but my selected option does not show the input to enter serial number.

Comment: You're getting that error because it cannot find the element you are searching for. I can't really help out without looking at what you have done. Do you have an updated codepen?

Comment: Yes, I have an update on my codepen.  I tried to use `document.getElementById(element).style.display='block';` but it didnt help out to find the element

Comment: Couple things: 1. Update your HTML to use "machineAccessoryRow-1" instead of "machineAccessoryRow-" for the existing row. Also update the select's onchange to use 1, not rowValue (as it doesn't contain the value you want). 2. Update your template to use name='bridgeFinisher' instead of id='bridgeFinishere' for the Bridge Finisher container.

Comment: Thanks @Nick it did work, changed few things like you said. The only problem is on the option for **others** you can take a look at the codepen. I will dig into the **others** option to see what's the problem.

Comment: Create a table for **other** machine accessories on its own when your can be able to just press add button without have to select others from dropdown list.